# Drag and drop try to assign file to input type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that is working in chrome but not working on ie11 and firefox...
when I research on internet because of security issue I can't pass.Is there any other way I can do

```
 var dt = e.dataTransfer || (e.originalEvent && e.originalEvent.dataTransfer);
    var files = dt.files;
    if (files) {
        // UploadFile(files[0]);
       // $('#file').val(files);
       $("#FileUploadForm input#file")[0].files = files;
        document.getElementById("filename").innerText = files[0].name;
    }
```